# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi doesn't work after software update

Tags: networking, drivers

My system has stopped detecting wifi after a software. `lshw -c network` gave the following output.

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: f8:da:0c:81:b4:4b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Previously, when I had this issue, the network was `UNCLAIMED` instead of `DISABLED`.

Thanks in advance for the help.